# How to jump a function using return

Tags: c

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun1();
void fun2();
int main() {
    printf("In main\n");
    fun1();
    printf("In main once again.\n");
    return 0;
}

void fun1()
{
    printf("in 1\n");
    fun2();
    printf("Still in 1\n");
}
void fun2()
{
    printf("in 2\n");
    return;
}
```

And here is the output

```
In main
in 1
in 2
Still in 1
In main once again.
```

So when I use return in *fun2()* the control goes back to *fun1()*. Is there a way to use return so that it directly goes back to main?

*I basically want to skip **still in 1** line*

Comment: No it is not. You could use some inline assembly to pop the return stack twice, but that is hacky as hell and there is no reason that would ever be the way to go

Comment: `setjmp`/`longjmp`

Comment: If you always want to skip `Still in 1`, then just remove that line. If you want to skip it depending on the situation, then let `fun2()` return a `bool` and check that. It's unclear what you want to achieve since the solution to not print `Still in 1` is so obvious.

Comment: Well this was just an example i basically wanna skip a part of program i am making, the program would be too big so i simply used a smaller example to demonstrate my problem, But that way of checking  it using a bool would work great i guess.

Comment: Here's how you could [conditionally skip `Still in 1`](https://godbolt.org/z/6Ws8E8foq) (but it's hardcoded to _always_ skip it).

Comment: @Virat and why do it like this instead of just an `if`?

Comment: My teacher tell us to minimize as much as possible and avoid having thousands of if else which make it confusing , so i wanted to know if there was a shorter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an interfunction goto facility, which is provided by the `setjmp`/`longjmp` standard library functions.
(There are some pretty strict restrictions on how these can be used. Beware of those: [http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.13.1.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.13.1.1) . Using `setjmp`/`longjmp` might not be the best way of solving your actual problem, but it is how you return to an indirect caller in C.).

In your example, you would use them as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h> //+
void fun1();
void fun2();
jmp_buf jb; //+
int main() {
    printf("In main\n");

    if (!setjmp(jb)) //+
        fun1();
    printf("In main once again.\n");
    return 0;
}

void fun1()
{
    printf("in 1\n");
    fun2();
    printf("Still in 1\n");
}
void fun2()
{
    printf("in 2\n");
    longjmp(jb,1); //+
    return;
}
```

*On how it works:*
The `setjmp` part needs to save after-the-call instruction pointer, the stack pointer and call-preserved registers (an intermediary function might use save-use-and-restore those call-preserved registers, if you `longjmp`, you'd be skipping the restore part, so that's why `setjmp` saves them and `longjmp` restores the save values) and `longjmp` then restore those values, setting the `setjmp`
return value to a nonzero provided as the `longjmp` argument or to 1, so that
the `setjmp` callsite can differentiate between a firstcall and a return from `longjmp`.

Comment: ngl I didn't entirely get it , a little too advanced for me, But i think this could get complicated easily , I guess i was looking for something like "return+" if it existed it allowed us to skip one tier of function and  something "return++" could allow us to skip two tiers of function..But i guess i doesn't.

Comment: @Virat Due to how how the function call machinery works in C, you can't have a `return++`. You can return arbitrary many layers, provided you've saved "return context".
Declaring `jmp_buf some_name_of_return_context;` allocates memory for the return context, `setjmp(some_name_of_return_context);` sets it, and `longjmp(some_name_of_return_context,value_to_return_from_setjmp);` then returns to it with the specified value, if nonzero, or with 1, so the setjmp callsite  can differentiate between a setup call to `setjmp` and a return through a `longjmp`. Not that difficult.

Comment: @Virat The paragraph about the registers will make sense if you learn assembly, but you can always think of the saved register data as a black-box "return-context" storable in a variable of type `jmp_buf`.

Comment: OK I guess I will try understanding and using it

Comment: @Virat Once you've understood it I can almost guarantee that you will not use it. Try to make well structured programs first and go crazy later.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Can't argue with that.